# razor page CSS is not working isolated, only with the style tag at the top

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, blazor

The question is almost self-explanatory. I have the razor component "board.razor" and it also has a "board.razor.css" which contains all the styles for that page. If I do it like that, then the styles won't get applied. If I insert the style classes on the top of the "board.razor", everything works like it should. I'll provide the code and the pictures for you.

Board.razor with style tag at top:

```
<style>
.dropzone {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e2eaf2;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 50%;
}

.no-drop {
    border: 2px dashed red;
    background-color: #e6d8d8;
}

.can-drop {
    border: 2px dashed green;
    background-color: #d8e6d8;
}

.draggable {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    max-width: 500px;
}

    .draggable:active {
        cursor: move;
        background: #f1f8ff;
    }

    .draggable:hover {
        cursor: move;
        background: #f1f8ff;
    }

h6 {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.dragging {
    cursor: move;
}

.description {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.sum {
    font-size: 17px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: midnightblue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.last-updated {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #474747;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .last-updated small {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #474747;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

h6 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.scrollbar {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.status-details[open] {
    transition: height 3s;
}

.status-details-summary {
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 8px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 3rem;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: white;
}

.status-container {
    display: flex;
}

.status-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.status-header {
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 21;
}

.status-header-item {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e2eaf2;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#bsettings {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
}
```

```
<NavBar OnIssueCreated="LoadIssues"></NavBar>
 
<div class="bodyContainer">
 
 
    @if (changeMenuShow)
    {
        <h3 style="padding-left:5px"><b>Aktive Sprints</b></h3>
    }
 
    @*<FilterBar AllIssues="issues"></FilterBar>*@
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-blue" style=" float: right; height: 38px; width: 41px; margin-left: 10px" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="oi oi-cog"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="/boardsettings" id="bsettings">Board Einstellungen(unfertig)</a></li>
            @*<li class="dropdown-item" @onclick="ModalShow">Board erstellen</li>*@
            @if (changeMenuShow)
            {
                <li class="dropdown-item" @onclick="MenuShow">Menüs ausblenden</li>
            }
            else if (!changeMenuShow)
            {
                <li class="dropdown-item" @onclick="MenuShow">Menüs einblenden</li>
            }
 
            @if (dialogType.Equals(EditDialogType.Sidebar))
            {
                <li class="dropdown-item" @onclick="DialogToModal">Vorgänge im Dialogfeld öffnen</li>
            }
            else if (dialogType.Equals(EditDialogType.Modal))
            {
                <li class="dropdown-item" @onclick="DialogToSidebar">Vorgänge in der Seitenleiste öffnen</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    @if (activeSprint != null)
    {
        <div style="float: right; margin-left: 10px ">
            <button style="height: 38px;" class="btn btn-blue" @onclick="Complete">Sprint abschließen</button>
        </div>
    }
 
 
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch" style="display: inline; float: left; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 10px">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="addMorebox" @bind="ShowOpenForToday" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="addMorebox">Heute zu erledigen anzeigen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch" style="display: inline; float: left; margin-top:8px; margin-left: 10px;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="addWaitReply" @bind="showWaitForReply" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="addWaitReply">Warte auf Rückmeldung anzeigen</label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <IssueDialogOpener DialogType="dialogType">
        <div class="scrollbar" style="height: 70vh; ">
            <header class="status-header">
                <div class="status-header-item">Zu Erledigen</div>
                @if (ShowOpenForToday)
                {
                    <div class="status-header-item">Heute zu Erledigen</div>
                }
                @if (showWaitForReply)
                {
                    <div class="status-header-item" style="display: inline;">Warte auf Rückmeldung</div>
                }
                <div class="status-header-item">In Arbeit</div>
                <div class="status-header-item">Fertig</div>
            </header>
            <div>
                @if (parentIssues.Count > 0)
                {
                    @foreach (var issue in parentIssues)
                    {
                        <SubtaskStatusContainer Issue="issue" ShowOpenForToday="@ShowOpenForToday" showWaitForReply="@showWaitForReply" OnChange="LoadIssues"></SubtaskStatusContainer>
                    }
                    @if (issues.Count != 0)
                    {
                        <StatusContainer Issues="@issues" ShowOpenForToday="@ShowOpenForToday" showWaitForReply="@showWaitForReply" OnChange="LoadIssues"></StatusContainer>
                    }
                }
                else if (issues.Count != 0)
                {
                    <StatusContainer IsWithoutSubtasks=true Issues="@issues" ShowOpenForToday="@ShowOpenForToday" showWaitForReply="@showWaitForReply" OnChange="LoadIssues"></StatusContainer>
                }
 
            </div>
        </div>
    </IssueDialogOpener>
</div>
```

How it looks:

[image]

How it looks with styles isolated in the board.razor.css:
[image]

Comment: I have encountered similar problem before, it seems the css isolation only apply if your component does not contains custom components. For example, if my component contains only genuine html tags, the generated css match the data id of corresponding tag. If the component contains tag from MudBlazor components, the data id will different. You can check whether the css did generated in browser dev tools.

Comment: Please show the code/html that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share how your reference the css in your view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For CSS from an Isolated css file to work in a sub component you need to use the `::deep` operator.  [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#child-component-support)

Comment: Asker is saying when he has styles in same file as component it works but it does not work with CSS isolation, using ::deep operator wont help here, he is not using ::deep in  styles in same file, but its working fine

Comment: It will work here read the docs. If you understood how isolation works. The subcomponents are not seeing the css. But with the ::Deep they will become "selectable". It does not matter that he is using and externally supplied Razor component either.

Comment: Read what asker said  "and it also has a "board.razor.css" which contains all the styles for that page. If I do it like that, then the styles won't get applied" and then he said  "If I insert the style classes on the top of the "board.razor", everything works like it should" Did you see any ::deep in his styles

Comment: @SurinderSingh I live in Lismore NSW we are under the severe Flooding search it on Google. When I can get reasonable net I will write a small demo for you. Hope that will help. I have written  several Razor libraries some are on NuGet. In Short using ::Deep in `board.razor.css` properly will make all style there available to it and all of its subcomponents.

Comment: I'm a trainee in software developement, so I wasn't able to answer since the weekend. His solution worked. I made someone missunderstand it I guess. 
I have "Backlog.razor" which contains several sub components. I wanted the styles to get applied to the subcomponents aswell (since almost the whole page are just sub components you can see). The styles get applied if I put them into backlog.razor but not if I put them into backlog.razor.css. I found the docs about css isolation in blazor already, but not about sub component support. I'm thankful for this answer and sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Push all styles back to Board.razor.css file

If your application is server-side then make sure if you have this line in your _Layout.cshtml

And if your application is Web Assembly then make sure this line is in your index.html file

```
<head>
    <link href="yourprojectname.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Comment: If you did that, it would apply your scoped CSS to the entire page. Don't do that. CSS isolation bundling will add the link for you, scoped to the page\component.