# Blazor WASM global style

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I know I can use CSS isolation in components but I want to add a global file for general style.
I added a CSS file to the wwwroot, how can I link it to the project?
Adding a link tag to the index html didn't help.

Comment: This question is already answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337474/razor-page-css-is-not-working-isolated-only-with-the-style-tag-at-the-top/71339328#71339328](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337474/razor-page-css-is-not-working-isolated-only-with-the-style-tag-at-the-top/71339328#71339328)

Answer (score 0):

In the head section of index.html file in wwwroot folder, just referencing properly should work.
For Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
```

Note that in this case, there is a css folder inside wwwroot.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer!

For everyone who might need it:

There a 3 steps:

1. Create a CSS file in the wwwroot under CSS folder.
2. Add tag in the index.html file for file CSS
   `<link href="css/{FILE-NAME}.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
3. Add tag in the index.html file for solution CSS
   `<link href="{SOLUTION-NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: There already is an `app.cs` file in that folder that you can edit. The `{SOLUTION-NAME}.styles.css` is already included.